# ToggleButton with custom image and custom text color

Tags: android, togglebutton, android-togglebutton

I have this toggle:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggle_1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_toggle_bg"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />
```

and this is drawable resources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/active" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default" android:state_checked="false"/>

</selector>
```

Now i would like that text of ToggleButton (on and off) change color when Toggle change state (only text, not background of entire ToggleButton).
How can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the attribute `android:textColor="@drawable/color_selector"` into your `<ToggleButton>`

```
//color_selector.xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" color="@color/text_on" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" color="@color/text_off" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make another selector in location `./res/color/my_selector.xml` and set it to `ToggleButton` `android:textColor="@color/my_selector"`

example `my_selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item color="@color/text_active" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item color="@color/text_default" android:state_checked="false"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: it's not drawable for text, is "color"

Answer (score 0):

In your code, use an `OnClickListener`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  final ToggleButton tb = new ToggleButton(DataHandler.getContext());
  tb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      if (tb.isChecked()) {
        tb.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
      }
      else {
        tb.setTextColor(Color.RED);
      }
    }
  });
}
```